# How to obtain downloaded file's name on VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, webclient

I have async threads downloading with `webClient.DownloadFileAsync()` and handled `downloadCompleted` event.

I want to know what is the file is just downloaded when the event is raising up. I tried with the sender of the event, but `webClient` doesn't have any method for this.

It's a desktop app for Windows, playing videos one after another. The dowloaded file's name is important because video's weight may be large and when one is downloaded the program must displayed it.

Right now the app, until all the files are downloaded, doesn't add the videos to the playlist because I don't know what the video downloaded is called. Videos are downloaded from a server.

```
     Private Sub myWebClient_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles myWebClient.DownloadFileCompleted
    Dim mySender As WebClient = CType(sender, WebClient)

   videoName = mysender.  'Here is where I try to obtain downloaded file's name
    Dim VideoFile1 As WMPLib.IWMPMedia3 = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(path & videoName)
    Playlist.appendItem(VideoFile1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call   `DownloadFileAsync` method, call with filename as argument like  `.DownloadFileAsync(url, filename, filename)` then you can get the file name as 
`Dim filename As String= CType(e.UserState, String)` in the `myWebClient_DownloadFileCompleted` method

Comment: In the case of event method in vb.NET usually is named 'e' like `Dim filename As String= CType(e.UserState, String)`. Thank both of you.